# Detect if WM_MOUSEMOVE is caused by touch/pen

Tags: c++, c, winapi, touch

I am experimenting with WM_TOUCH and want to detect if mouse events are synthesized from touch/pen events or due to an *actual* mouse event.

The official solution according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is to check if the result of `GetMessageExtraInfo()` has the upper 24 bits set to `0xFF515700`.

This works. *Most* of the time. If I use one finger, all is well and good, but if I use more than one, releasing the last one causes a mouse move with `GetMessageExtraInfo() == 0`. Also, when the window loses focus via touch, up to 3 mouse move messages with `GetMessageExtraInfo() == 0` are generated.

Is there a *reliable* way of disambiguating between mouse, touch and pen inputs?

Comment: To the downvoter, please explain what you didn't like about the question.

Answer (score 8):

The link you posted does show the only reliable way to discern between mouse messages generated by a physical mouse, and those synthesized in response to touch and pen input.

For completeness, here is the fully working code. The code relies on state that is valid only while handling a mouse message. Calling it at any other time has undefined behavior:

```
bool IsTouchEvent() {
    const LONG_PTR c_SIGNATURE_MASK = 0xFFFFFF00;
    const LONG_PTR c_MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH = 0xFF515700;

    LONG_PTR extraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();
    return ( ( extraInfo & c_SIGNATURE_MASK ) == c_MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH );
}
```

The additional `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages you are observing, are an artifact of how the system implements its internal bookkeeping. For example, if a window is shown or hidden, the mouse cursor may be over a different window now, and needs to be recalculated. To do this, the system synthesizes an artificial `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message.

This effect is explained in Raymond Chen's blog: [Why do I get spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE messages?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031001-00/?p=42343).

Comment: I suspected that something like that is happening, however storing the mouse position and ignoring repeated messages works when changing focus away from the window, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Joe: Those `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages are unrelated to touch input. They will be generated on systems, where no touch input device is present as well. If you need to find a way to filter out those messages, you'd probably have to ask a new question.

Comment: If the events corresponded to an actual previous mouse move (not a touch) I wouldn't care, as the values correspond to the previous/next mouse move anyways. However they are caused by a touch event (to a different window).

Comment: You'll find when filtering Touch inputs from WM_MOUSEMOVE that the final move upon touch pointer release says it is from Mouse device. All the previous ones come from Touch via the extra info.  This is a nuisance if you are trying to code different touch & mouse behavior in an application. Most WM_MOUSEMOVES from touch are white lies, but the final one is nasty!

Comment: @Greg: I believe the final `WM_MOUSEMOVE` isn't related to touch input at all. It's the *let's wrap things up by sending a fake mouse move* message, that gets generated on non-touch systems as well. Sure, it gets in the way when interpreting touch input, but it's the same message you get, when bringing another window into the foreground using the mouse.