# Windows Touch and Mouse events

Tags: c++, winapi, touchscreen

We have an application built on an older framework (Qt 3.3.5) that we would prefer not to have to attempt to upgrade to recognize touch events.

We recently upgraded it from `win32-msvc2005` to `win32-msvc2013`. For the most part this has gone just fine, but tablets (for testing purposes, a Surface Pro on Windows 8.1) that sent mouse events when compiled against 2005 now send only `WM_POINTER` events when the touch screen is used in the 2013 compiled application.

I have been completely unable to find a way to get Windows to send me mouse events for touchscreen input again. My research implies that if I register for `WM_TOUCH` events I should [also get mouse events](http://the-witness.net/news/2012/10/wm_touch-is-totally-bananas/) (as indicated by many people on the internet angry about getting mouse events with their `WM_TOUCH` events), but my (supposedly) successful calls to [`RegisterTouchWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) don't seem to actually enable the `WM_TOUCH` events (or any mouse events), and I am still receiving pointer events.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, especially with not being able to get `WM_TOUCH` events (which I don't even want, but would supposedly get me mouse events), but whatever it is continues to elude me. (Presumably it would have to be `RegisterTouchWindow` not being called for the specific `hwnd` I am actually touching on the screen, but I've gone so far as putting a `RegisterTouchWindow` call in specifically upon seeing any `WM_POINTERUPDATE` event for the `hwnd` that spawned the event, and outputting the result of the Register call upon it returning true and it is returning true, so that seems impossible as the cause.)

I'm also calling `DefWindowProc` on all `WM_TOUCH/GESTURE/POINTER` events, which is the only other thing the internet seems to think might be necessary for events to bubble into more basic events correctly. The framework does not call `RegisterRawInputDevices` and does not attempt to handle `WM_INPUT` events (which it wouldn't receive anyway thanks to not being registered for raw input). Any events not handled explicitly should fall through to a `DefWindowProc` call.

Is there even a way that older applications like ours can move to a newer msvc without going through the pain of teaching the framework to correctly handle the various touch protocols? How does an application that worked just fine on msvc2005 using the built in windows touch to mouse events conversion get that functionality back in msvc2013?

Comment: I am curious as to the framework you are using.  I have an MFC application that seems to work just fine with older single touch terminals. What I am seeing is mouse events and button events. I even was able to use mouse events to make a primitive drag to scroll interface for an MFC view.  Your posting makes me nervous about using multi-touch screens with my application.

Comment: Have you tried disabling raw input, by commenting out the code that calls [RegisterRawInputDevices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600.aspx)? This is not a solution, just a way to isolate the issue. Likewise, have you implemented a simple raw Windows API prototype to verify, whether or not the observed behavior is part of the framework, or the API. A potential solution could be to manifest your application to be compatible with Windows 7 (vs. Windows 8 and above).

Comment: @RichardChambers Qt 3.3.5, and it is fine on these same tablets with the same code when compiled to 2005, it seems to have been a side effect of upgrading to the newer visual studio. We actually did the same thing (adding drag to scroll functionality based on mouse events) which worked great for our limited touch device needs until the 2013 upgrade.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry, My `WM_INPUT` comment was misleading, we don't seem to use raw input at all (I mostly mentioned it because improperly handling `WM_INPUT` events is known to prevent `WM_TOUCH` events).

Comment: @IInspectable When you say to manifest the application to be compatible with Windows 7 are you referring to the compatibility section [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or something else? That didn't seem to help when I added it (tried both vista and win7), and all attempts at setting windows compatibility levels on the executable failed to change the behavior also. 

I have not attempted to create minimal projects to verify the API vs the framework, vs our full project yet, but I suppose I probably should.

Comment: Just to rule out an obvious source of problems: When you upgraded to VS 2013 you also linked against a different Qt implementation (Qt modules must be compatible with the respective CRT). If I'm not mistaken, Qt can be compiled without touch input support. Please double-check whether your compiled Qt binaries have touch input support enabled. I'd still recommend writing a pure Windows API test project, to see if there have been changes in the platform (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29866664/1889329) for instructions on identifying mouse input generated by the system).