# Configure touch on Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have laptop with touch screen and Windows 8 installed.

I have windows form with nothing on it and I just want to handle WM_LBUTTON_DOWN and WM_LBUTTON_UP messages.

Here is what I get:

1. I press my form on touch screen and see that there is no
   WM_LBUTON_DOWN message.
2. I release my form and see that
   WM_LBUTTON_DOWN and WM_LBUTTON_UP messages appeared.

Problem is **I do not receive WM_LBUTTONDOWN message when I press the form**. WM_LBUTTONDOWN message appears only when I release the form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TouchExample
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool RegisterTouchWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int flags);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern bool UnregisterTouchWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);

            RegisterTouchWindow(Handle, 0);
        }

        protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            UnregisterTouchWindow(Handle);

            base.OnFormClosing(e);
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            // l button down
            if (m.Msg == 0x201)
            {
                // do something
            }
            // r button down
            else if (m.Msg == 0x202)
            {
                // do something
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I change that behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is by design, and it cannot be changed. The reason is simply, that with touch input the system cannot decide on first contact, whether this is going to be the equivalent of a left mouse button down, or just the beginning of a long press, that translates to a right button down message.

If you wish to implement a responsive touch optimized UI you'll have to call [RegisterTouchWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317326.aspx) (optionally passing the `TWF_WANTPALM` flag), and handle [WM_TOUCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317341.aspx) messages instead of the compatibility mouse messages.

If you are handling `WM_TOUCH` messages, you can filter out the mouse messages generated for compatibility with applications that do not implement dedicated touch input. How to identify those 'fake' mouse messages is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29866664/1889329).