# How to distinguish WM_MOUSE*** messages generated by touch pad from generated by mouse device?

Tags: windows, winapi, input, touch

I've tried `GetMessageExtraInfo()` mentioned here:
[Detect if WM_MOUSEMOVE is caused by touch/pen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857587/detect-if-wm-mousemove-is-caused-by-touch-pen)

but it does not work - `GetMessageExtraInfo()` returns `0` for all mouse events generated by touch pad.

Tried it on notebook with integral touchpad and on desktop PC with external touch pad attached.

I also tried to use WM_TOUCH event with `RegisterTouchWindow()` and `WM_GESTURE` but they do not work either - I am not receiving neither `WM_TOUCH` nor `WM_GESTURE` events on the window.

Essentially what I need is to detect when finger is on and off touch pad. But it seems that WM_TOUCH or WM_GESTURE work only for touch displays but not for touch pads, for unknown reasons.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

If you require being able to distinguish the input source, consider using `WM_POINTER*` messages instead of the older `WM_MOUSE*` messages. Note that this will require calling [`EnableMouseInPointer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablemouseinpointer) to receive messages about devices the system considers a mouse (which is true for many basic touch-pads).

Unlike the `WM_MOUSE*` messages, where the `wParam` tells you the state of certain virtual keys, the `WM_POINTER` messages includes enough information to be able to track the input source. It is somewhat more complicated in that pointer messages do not provide separate messages depending on which button was pressed, but that information is at least still available.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it should work but unfortunately it does not.

`EnableMouseInPointer(TRUE);` and `WM_POINTER***` do not give any meaningful results - WM_POINTERWHEEL gives exactly same results on external touchpad  (Apple Magic Trackpad over bluetooth). GetPointerInfo reports messages are coming from mouse.

Comment: Most touchpads emulate a mouse at the hardware level. As far as Windows can tell, the events are coming from a mouse.

Comment: @RaymondChen I understand that. I am trying to reproduce MacOS's behavior when touchpad scroll uses kinetic/inertia/overscroll effect and mouse wheel uses instant scroll (-position update). Seems like kinetic/inertia/overscroll cannot be reasonably implemented without WM_TOUCH/WM_GESTURE coming from touchpad. 

MacOS sends `touchesBegan/EndedWithEvent` message that help to distinguish the behavior even if using emulated mouseWheel, mouseMove, etc.

Comment: @RaymondChen, it appears as DirectManipulation is capable to distinguish wheel from touchpad.  At least there is a DM_POINTERHITTEST message being sent when a) DM is active and b) user starts interacting with touchpad. 

It would be terribly nice and polite to send something like WM_INTERACTION_START(device), WM_INTERACTION_END(device) by Windows. 

Something semantically close to touchesBegan/End ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan?language=objc ) events.

Comment: @c-smile If you have an Enhanced Touchpad, then GetPointerInfo can distinguish them.

Comment: @RaymondChen, what is that Enhanced Touchpad exactly? And how is it different from Precision Touchpad for example ? I have three different models of those, neither one gets identified by GetPointerInfo.

Comment: Sorry, I was working from memory. Precision touchpad.