# How to distinguish mouse and touchpad events using GetCurrentInputMessageSource()?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-c++

I'm working on a WPF requirement, in which I have to distinguish events/messages from touchpad and mouse. After doing a bit of research I came across the below example.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8233d8fe-5665-46db-9f0f-e0ed83cccbcc/how-to-identify-an-input-event-is-from-touchpad-or-mouse?forum=vclanguage

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/535824/find-button-click-event-is-from-mouse-or-touchoad.html)

```
 [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 private static extern bool GetCurrentInputMessageSource(out INPUT_MESSAGE_SOURCE inputMessageSource);
    
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 public struct INPUT_MESSAGE_SOURCE
 {
     public INPUT_MESSAGE_DEVICE_TYPE deviceType;
     public INPUT_MESSAGE_ORIGIN_ID originId;
 }
    
 public enum INPUT_MESSAGE_DEVICE_TYPE
 {
     IMDT_UNAVAILABLE = 0x00000000,      // not specified
     IMDT_KEYBOARD = 0x00000001,      // from keyboard
     IMDT_MOUSE = 0x00000002,      // from mouse
     IMDT_TOUCH = 0x00000004,      // from touch
     IMDT_PEN = 0x00000008,      // from pen
     IMDT_TOUCHPAD    = 0x00000010,      // from touchpad
 }
    
 public enum INPUT_MESSAGE_ORIGIN_ID
 {
     IMO_UNAVAILABLE = 0x00000000,  // not specified
     IMO_HARDWARE = 0x00000001,  // from a hardware device or injected by a UIAccess app
     IMO_INJECTED = 0x00000002,  // injected via SendInput() by a non-UIAccess app
     IMO_SYSTEM = 0x00000004,  // injected by the system
 }
    
 public const int WM_MOUSEFIRST = 0x0200;
 public const int WM_MOUSELAST = 0x020E;
 public const int WM_KEYFIRST = 0x0100;
 public const int WM_KEYLAST = 0x0109;
 public const int WM_TOUCH = 0x0240;
 public const int WM_POINTERWHEEL = 0x024E;
    
    
 protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
     HwndSource hWndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
     hWndSource.AddHook(WndProc);
 }
    
 private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
 {
     if ((msg >= WM_MOUSEFIRST && msg <= WM_MOUSELAST) || (msg >= WM_KEYFIRST && msg <= WM_KEYLAST) || (msg >= WM_TOUCH && msg <= WM_POINTERWHEEL))
     {
         INPUT_MESSAGE_SOURCE ims = new INPUT_MESSAGE_SOURCE();
         GetCurrentInputMessageSource(out ims); 
         if (ims.deviceType == INPUT_MESSAGE_DEVICE_TYPE.IMDT_MOUSE)
         {
             Console.Beep(6000, 5);
         }
         // not tested
         else if (ims.deviceType == INPUT_MESSAGE_DEVICE_TYPE.IMDT_TOUCHPAD)
         {
             Console.Beep(2000, 5);
         }
     }
     return IntPtr.Zero;
 }
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to make it work. GetCurrentInputMessageSource() returns deviceType 'IMDT_MOUSE' even if I use the touchpad. Any idea what's wrong?

Environment: Windows 10 version 1909, Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I remember experiencing the same thing years ago when playing around with detecting a screen touch (which works well), but curiously could never get `IMDT_TOUCHPAD` to trigger. I just tested again -on an obviously much newer laptop- and it still doesn't. If you're really keen, you could probably look at using `GetRawInputData`, which unfortunately is significantly more complex. Here's a [project](https://github.com/ichisadashioko/windows-touchpad) that uses it, and has some good reading material.

Comment: @NPras Thank you, I have already implemented a solution using GetRawInputData() by referring the same project. But it's not very flexible and robust for my requirement. For the most part (about 90% cases), it works fine but I was trying to get some better alternatives.

Comment: I had the same problem without reasonable solution. Check comment of Raymond Chen in my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851594/how-to-distinguish-wm-mouse-messages-generated-by-touch-pad-from-generated-by

Comment: @c-smile, I won't disagree with *the* Raymond Chen, but when Win10's own settings panel says "Your PC has a precision touchpad" and allows you to configure "tap with a single finger to single-click" all the way to 4-fingered gestures, I wonder if it's something more than just the touchpad pretending to be a mouse.