# How to detect if TouchDown event occurred instead of mouse click when user clicks my App Icon located on Windows TaskBar?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi, touch

I am monitoring the mouse/keyboard/touch-screen interactions of my Taskbar icons from the Win32 app in order to make custom behaviours for the icon.

What Win32 API could be used instead of GetCursorPos() to get the x,y where touch-screen was clicked (from other process)?

It seems GetCursorPos() only works for the mouse cursor, not when a finger events occur.

Comment: Complex issue that revolves around the `WM_TOUCH` message and its handler(s). [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/windows-touch-portal). Not sure how (or even *if*) any of the stuff covered there is implemented in Delphi, though.

Comment: @AdrianMole Modern Delphi versions already support touch capability. In fact Touch capability was added back in Delphi 2010. There is also an article showing of how to add touch support to Delphi 7 [here](http://www.tecepe.com.br/d7gestures/).

Comment: @SilverWarior Good to know (I've haven't used Delphi, or even VCL in C++, for quite some time). I assumed, from the reference to `GetCursorPos`, the OP was looking to use the WinAPI.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes Delphi touch support is quite impressive. It works in both VCL and FMX. And it works on all supported platforms by Delphi like Windows, MacOS, iOS, Androird, and I believe also Linux. Well for Linux you do need FMX for Linux library that is not part of the default Delphi package but needs to be added separately. Standard gestures are also supported. And you can make even your own custom gestures if you wish. Best thing about gestures in Delphi is that they also respond to mouse input and not only touch input. Of course this does limits you to single point gestures.

Comment: Make sure you understand that making a problem go away and solving a problem are entirely different things.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to monitor if 3rd party window/process was touched in a similar way that GetCursorPos() works.

Comment: Touch input, in general, supports more than one point of interaction, making an equivalent to `GetCursorPos` ambiguous. By default, the system generates compatibility mouse messages in response to touch input. If necessary, those messages [can be identified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29866664/1889329). Though, as always, it remains unclear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks, so is it possible to listen for  WM_MOUSEMOVE messages that occur over 3rd party window handles and then check (extraInfo & c_SIGNATURE_MASK ) == c_MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid you can't get touch information from other process since since Touch Input Handle is valid only within the current process and should not be passed cross-process.

Comment: What makes you think that [raw input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) wouldn't be capable of observing global touch input events?

Comment: Because in order for application to receive touch messages it must first register one of more of its windows for receiving Touch Messages. These touch messages are then sent to those specific registered Windows by Windows Touch driver. That is if the touch has been made over the specific window area. You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/getting-started-with-multi-touch-messages#registering-to-receive-windows-touch-input)

Comment: That is because Windows Touch Driver is not creating RAW input data but instead forwarding specific WM_TOUCH messages to specific Window that was previously registered so that it can receive such messages. RAW input supports three input data types `RAWMOUSE`, `RAWKEYBOARD` and `RAWHID`. While some touch surfaces have HID compliant drivers there is no guarantee for this to be true.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a touch input driver that produces input events that escape raw input, yet still generates valid `WM_TOUCH` messages if requested?